# Set an incrementing default for a work item field

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem

We want to set the iteration path to a default our tree structure is as follows

Root

- v10.1
- v10.2
- v10.3

So we want it to prefill with the latest (v10.3) on creating each new work item.. and in future when we add v10.4 it would then pre-fill that instead.

Are either the default or dynamic update to new iteration paths possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have a rule in your work item to default the iteration path. 
That said, in TFS11 iterations are first class citizens: they have dates.

The product now knows what is the current sprint/iteration for a team. If you create a new work item in the context of that team it will default the iteration path with that iteration.

See more on teams in TFS11 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528603(v=vs.110).aspx